Resizing windows forms for different monitor resolution
I made a windows form on a QHD monitor. Can I somehow scale it down so it would fit fullhd monitor and look exactly the same like on QHD???
I could not find anything on the internet that could do this.
Please help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
